# Elasticsearch is having Sudden High CPU with GC

Tags: elasticsearch, garbage-collection, elastic-stack, cpu-usage, elk

We are using ELS v 7.5.2 on nodes (7 node cluster) with RAM total 32GB, 16GB allocated to ES.
Elasticsearch nodes are having high CPU spikes from time to time with GC.

Any suggestion or idea of a reason for this?

Below are the diagrams of a node that has this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 7.5 is EOL - https://www.elastic.co/support/eol - you should really upgrade :) however there's nothing in your screenshots that indicates sustained high GC or CPU. you've got a pretty nice sawtooth increase of heap use, then a GC run with a spike in CPU, then a drop in heap use. that looks totally normal